# SQL select multiple rows as one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Table**

| ID | Date | Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6255 | 2018-01-31 | HZH98CC | 435.34 |
| 6256 | 2018-01-31 | CVVCDE7 | 23.24 |
| 6257 | 2018-01-31 | WWRT423 | 24.24 |
| 6258 | 2018-02-14 | DT4 | 43.23 |
| 6259 | 2018-02-14 | D42C | 243.2 |

How can I use query/view to get **All** the records from the DB table and combine rows with same date into one row? I am not sure how to start on it. I've tried `FOR XML` but I am not getting the result I want

```
SELECT DISTINCT transactions.[id], 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+ transactions.model  AS [text()]
            FROM transactions
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) transactions
FROM transactions
```

Which returns

| ID | Model |
| --- | --- |
| 6255 | HZH98CC,CVVCDE7,WWRT423,DT4,D42C |

**Expected Outcome**

| ID | Date | Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6255,6256,6257 | 2018-01-31 | HZH98CC,CVVCDE7,WWRT423 | 435.34,23.24,24.24 |
| 6258,6259 | 2018-02-14 | DT4,D42C | 43.23,243.2 |

Is this in anyway possible or do I have to do

```
Select distinct [date]
From transactions Order by [date]
```

and the use the resulting dates to SELECT the matching rows and combine them in code later?

I need all cells from the matching rows (i.e. rows with the same date) to be concatenated into the cell of that column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: You can use this. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712374/how-to-convert-multiple-rows-to-one-row-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712374/how-to-convert-multiple-rows-to-one-row-in-sql-server)

Comment: Please refine (or simplify) your expected outcome example.  As it stands it makes no sense to aggregate the model strings and randomly include only one of their prices.

Comment: @Gowthaman link may be the one. i will test it and get back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2017, SQL Server has supported [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select date,
       string_agg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids,
       string_agg(model, ',') within group (order by id) as model,
       string_agg(price, ',') within group (order by id) as prices
from transactions
group by date;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you have to use the XML work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Example using XML for older versions of SQL Server that do not have string_agg function.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
    id varchar(10),
    date date, 
    model varchar(10),
    price varchar(10)
    )

INSERT INTO @t
select 6255 ,'2018-01-31',  'HZH98CC',  435.34 union all
select 6256 ,'2018-01-31',  'CVVCDE7',  23.24 union all
select 6257 ,'2018-01-31',  'WWRT423',  24.24 union all
select 6258 ,'2018-02-14',  'DT4',  43.23 union all
select 6259 ,'2018-02-14',  'D42C', 243.2;

 SELECT 
  stuff( ( SELECT ','+ [id] FROM @t WHERE date = t1.date FOR XML PATH('') 
                     ),1,1,'') id,
  date,  
  stuff( ( SELECT ','+ [model] FROM @t WHERE date = t1.date FOR XML PATH('') 
                     ),1,1,'') model,
  stuff( ( SELECT ','+ [price] FROM @t WHERE date = t1.date FOR XML PATH('') 
                     ),1,1,'')  price
FROM (SELECT distinct date FROM @t ) t1
```